# Search some contents and update it in Eclipse search view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created Eclipse plugin to search some contents and update it in eclipse search view, but I am unable to do so since `createControl()` of `ISearchResultPage` is called only once in its life cycle.

I need to call it every time my search result changes so that I can erase all the previous widgets and update my search result using new widgets accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `createContents` method is only ever called once. What you can do in your result page is use an `IQueryListener` to listen for changes to queries.

Add the listener in the `createContents` method with:

```java
NewSearchUI.addQueryListener(queryListener);
```

You should remove the listener in the page `dispose` method:

```java
NewSearchUI.removeQueryListener(queryListener);
```

Note that the `org.eclipse.search.ui.text.AbstractTextSearchViewPage` does this for you, you may be able to extend that page rather than write your own complete `ISearchResultPage` page.

Comment: I had managed that in a different way earlier by hiding and opening the search view every time the search result changes. I will now try with the way you have said.. However I am now facing a new problem. i.e,  I am unable to get the NUMBER of matches found to show in the search view although search result(matches) exist and displayed in the search view. I am getting the NUMBER of matches found in the previous search but not that of the current search. I tried with match event but still same problem exists.. Please help me.

Comment: the way you said is working.. thanks for that but the above problem still exists.. I am not getting number of matches when I display the result on the view